# MemoryAnalyzer на живом примере

Tags: android, утечка-памяти, memory-management

Ни разу не пользовался MemoryAnalyzer, но возникла необходимость. Universal Image Loader стал делать слишком большие аллокации памяти, возможно причина в том, что я добавил собственный LayoutManager(так как recyclerview, для которого uil подгружает изображения вынужден находиться в scrollview). LayoutManager привожу ниже, а так же скриншот из МемориАналайзера, вызов Finalazer'а идет циклически и очень много раз, никак не могу понять причину. Если поможете разобраться, куда копать, буду весьма признателен.

```
public class NestedGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {


    private int spanCount;
    private Context context;
    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    public NestedGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context, spanCount);
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1] / spanCount;
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0] * spanCount;
            }
        }

        if (getItemCount() % 2 == 1) {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1] / spanCount;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {

        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);

        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);

            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            if (measuredDimension[0] > metrics.widthPixels / spanCount) {
                measuredDimension[0] = metrics.widthPixels / spanCount;
            }
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

EDIT
Ошибки UIL для примера

```
UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [null]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))


java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [null]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
                                                                  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:280)
                                                                  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:99)
                                                                  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
                                                                  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
                                                                  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
                                                                  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Нужно уточнить вопрос, вы ошибку об утечке памяти получаете, если да, то нужно подумать, если нет, то чего раньше времени панику подымать?

Comment: Есть утечка, при том весьма весомая. Попытался откатить до стандартного LayoutManager, отработало на ура, но он схлопвается в ScrollView.

Comment: Я не об этом, вы ошибку **stackoverflove** получаете? Приложение падает?

Comment: Приложение даже не отгружает gridview, не хватает ресурсов. При этом в логе громадный стек сообщений об аллокации влоть до 128мб и Ошибок UIL. При том, как я уже писал выше со стандартным LM такого нет

Comment: А что хоть за ошибки UIL?